# connect pydev to wsl python

Tags: python, eclipse, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pydev

I use eclipse and pydev on windows.
I need to develop on airflow, that works on linux and on wsl, but not on windows.
I have a working wsl-based os (an ubuntu) with a working venv with airflow installed and running.

I was wondering if I can set up a python interpreter in pydev that points to the "wsl" python and obtain the various pydev integrations (from the autocomplete to the debugging)

Answer (score 1):

Without having tried it myself, I believe the chances of using the Windows version of Eclipse/PyDev to develop using the Linux version of Python is unlikely.

While it seems that PyDev has [remote debugging capabilities](https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html), I can't be sure if this works cross-platform.  Even if it does, pay close attention to the note at the bottom of that page:

> the file pydevd_file_utils.py must be edited to make the path translations from the client machine to the server machine and vice-versa. See the comments on that file for detailed instructions on setting the path translations.

That's going to involve some pretty serious Windows <-> WSL/Linux path translations.  You might try to rely on the `wslpath` executable in WSL as a helper for that.

As for completions, that's where I really doubt that it's possible using Windows Eclipse/PyDev with Linux/WSL Python.

My suggestion would be to instead run the Linux version of Eclipse/PyDev under WSL.  You'll need a system capable of running Linux GUI apps, of course.  Under Windows 11, that's fairly straightforward with the WSLg feature.  See my [answer yesterday on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1393173/1165986) for more options.

I just did a quick test and was able to run Linux Eclipse/PyDev under Ubuntu in WSL2.  I did run into some issues with some dialogs not being the right size (and not resizable), but I was still able to complete the installation.  If you decide to go this route and find you need assistance, let me know and I'll attempt to go further with it.